# XmlSchemaElement sort order in C#

Tags: c#, xsd

I am comparing two XMLs based on the same XMLSchema.
Every Element within the XML has an id (id says nothing about the order - the oldest xmlElement has the lowest id and so on).
My goal would be to get sort of an alignment between the two XMLS.

To give a very simple example.
Let there be two xmls. The first one looks like this:

```
<EleType>
    <Ele id="1"/>
    <Name id="2"/>
    <Description id="100"/>
    <UnknownOrderEle1 id="3"/>
</EleType>
```

and the second one like this:

```
<EleType>
    <Ele id="1"/>
    <Name id="2"/>
    <Description id="100"/>
    <UnknownOrderEle2 id="4"/>
</EleType>
```

My result should be a mapping of ids.
It will start off nicely with 1:1, then 2:2, 100:100. At this moment I come across two xml elements with differing names. I know they may not be matched, so the two possible solutions would be to take 3:* (where * = symbol for no match) and then *:4 or to take *:4 and then 3:*.
BUT only one way is the correct solution because the schema says that UnknownOrderEle2 (id=4) should come before UnknownOrderEle1 (id=3.

So I looked for anything within the XmlSchema class, `XmlSchemaInfo`, `XmlSchemaElement`,... that tells me anything about the element order. The only two possibilities I found are no real solutions for me, since they are either too time consuming or unclean.
One would be to compare the `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` within the `XmlSchemaObject` (probably unclean).
The other one would be to construct an xml out of the two xmls and validate it. If it throws a validation exception I know that the order that I picked was wrong (definitely time consuming).

I would be glad to receive any help if anybody knows a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The schema corresponding to your example should contain something like this:

```
<xs:element name="EleType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Ele">
        . . .
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Name">
        . . .
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Description">
        . . .
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="UnknownOrderEle1">
        . . .
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="UnknownOrderEle2">
        . . .
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Once loaded, you can get hold of the corresponding `XmlSchemaElement` object and then of the order of its sub-elements with some code like this:

```
XmlSchemaElement element = schema.Elements[new XmlQualifiedName("EleType")];
XmlSchemaType complexType = (XmlSchemaComplexType)element.ElementSchemaType;
XmlSchemaSequence sequence = (XmlSchemaSequence)complexType.Particle;
XmlSchemaObjectCollection childElements = sequence.Items;
```

`childElements` is the list of the valid sub-elements `Ele`, `Name`, `Description`, `UnknownOrderEle1`, `UnknownOrderEle2`,  in the correct order.

This works as long as your schema is simple, but if the definition of the types are not simple sequences but more complex - with `choice`, groups and so on, it becomes much more complex, to the point that the other approach to create an XML file and try to validate it becomes probably better.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. My schema is more complicated but the comparisons also are a very limiting factor. I am comparing hundreds of XMLs recursively, so I simply can't validate every possible compare difference. I'll try the more complex approach according to your solution and will post it here if it is not too long ;-)